# Custom security trimmer for Sharepoint 2016

Tags: development, search-results, 2016, security-trimming

We are implementing a web part which will show all the site collections on which user has access(Admin/Member/Read).

But we don't want to show site collections , on which user has access through Everyone/All Authenticated Users group access.

Can anybody tell me how to implement security Pre-trimming for SharePoint 2016 Server search results which will trim site collections which have access to user through Everyone/All Authenticated Users groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below instructions apply at least to **2013** version of SP (got no 2016 to verify how they'd work on it).

---

You can query all sites of the site index by using a Content Search Web Part and by setting your own query. The query such as

```
`contentclass:STS_Site path:"https://yourlocation" -Path={Site.URL}
```

does the job for this. Here

- `contentclass:STS_Site` defines the return type to SharePoint site collections;
- `path:"https://yourlocation"` defines the path to be queried including the URL itself and all the subsites below that level. Note that this returns also the possible subsubsites, etc.
- `-Path={Site.URL}` excludes the site the web part is located at. This is what you need if you want to search the sites below the current site level, but if you'd search for sites from another location, you could exclude the parent level by e.g. its name - `SiteTitle<>SiteName` where `<>` means `Not equals`.

Now as you want to exclude results where the permission has been given through the user group, you need to supplement the above query with

```
-AssignedTo:Everyone
```

Where `-` gives the negation. So the final query would be:

```
`contentclass:STS_Site path:"https://yourlocation" -Path={Site.URL} -AssignedTo:Everyone
```

If you are interested about further query building possibilities with a CSWP, have a look at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj683123.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

---

It's possible, that the returned site collections on the CSWP are formatted as texts without links to the actual paths, which would require a bit further work as detailed below:

For the link you need to customize an available property. From the site collection's root level access *Search Schema* -settings, search for an available (non-customized) `RefinableStringXX` where XX is a number from 00 to 99. Choose *Edit/Map Property* for the selected property. On the *Mappings to crawled properties* open *Add a Mapping*, search for `ows_SiteName` and add it. Now you can use the customized `RefinableString` property on the CSWP.

Note that the changes to the customized property will be applied during the next incremental crawl. The same applies for the CSWP generally - the crawled items will update after the incremental crawls.

---

Note the difference between **Everyone** and **All Authenticated Users**:

- All Authenticated Users: Active Directory accounts and other accounts (External/MicrosoftID/etc.)
- Everyone: AD accounts, other accounts and Anonymous users

Comment: Sorry - but I doubt this will work! The AssignedTo property maps to ows_AssignedTo and just allows you to query tasks assigned to a user. It is not related to site permissions. You can indeed query site collections with the query contentclass:STS_Site. But it will return ALL site collections that the current user has read access to no matter how the permission is granted. The SharePoint search engine does not index permissions for querying - only for security trimming.

Comment: @LarsFastrup I fail to see how `AssignedTo` would work only with Task items. I know it can be used with them, and likely is used with the built-in assigned task collector. `AssignedTo` is a queryable and retrievable managed property although not searchable, just as e.g. `Path` is.

Comment: Correct - it will work with any list item using this field. I'm just saying it's not related to SharePoint permissions.

Comment: @LarsFastrup I think you are correct. I was only able to simulate the query on my limited env where the returns at least happened to indicate it would work, but that might not be the case.

Comment: @LarsFastrup is right . Query suggested isn't working .

Comment: Can anybody has any alternate suggestion ?